# Tortoise SVN - Checkouts for repositories with many tags/branches

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn, checkout

When doing a checkout using Tortoise SVN, if a repository has the trunk, as well as many branches/tags, won't the checkout time grow quite a bit over time?

Every time a checkout is done from the root, it will have to checkout the trunk, all branches, and all tags ... or am I missing something here.

Comment: ["Subversion does not have special commands for branching or tagging, but uses so-called “cheap copies” instead. Cheap copies are similar to hard links in Unix, which means that instead of making a complete copy in the repository, an internal link is created, pointing to a specific tree/revision. As a result branches and tags are very quick to create, and take up almost no extra space in the repository."](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html) - So if I am understanding this right, each branch/tag generally takes up no additional space.

Comment: "No additional space" **on server**, not in Working Copy

Comment: Don't checkout root, only needed subtree of repo (one branch, one trunk)

Answer (score 3):

**It will only grow over time if you're *doing it wrong***. SVN is not meant to check out entire repository trees with all branches and tags. That could very quickly eat up all available hard disk space on large repositories with a lot of branches and tags.

Instead, just check out the single branch or trunk or tag that you need. You can always use `svn switch` to switch between them in a single working copy if you like.

If you *must* have multiple branches in one working copy for some reason (perhaps you want to do some major moving around between branches or something) then you should create a [sparse working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.9/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) containing only the branches you need, to prevent taking up needless disk space and bandwidth.

Note, TortoiseSVN has a nice "Choose items..." dialog on the checkout dialog and "update to revision" dialog that allows you to quickly create a sparse working copy with exactly the content you want.